# Validating form data that uses a selector with Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am attempting to automate checking the values of a form. I figured out how to check the values submitted via send_keys, but anything submitted via a selector is giving me trouble. I'm a n00b when it comes to automation.

**This works:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='CurrentAddress.LineOne'][@value='123 Something Lane']")
```

**This does not:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='CurrentAddress.StateAbbrev'][@value='TX']")
```

The code that governs the CurrentAddress.StateAbbrev is

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="* State is required" id="CurrentAddress_StateAbbrev" name="CurrentAddress.StateAbbrev"><option value=""></option>
```

When I try to validate the State, I get this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@name='CurrentAddress.StateAbbrev'][@value='TX']"}
```

The form value stores the input as 'TX' but the page shows the State as 'TEXAS'. I've tried looking for either, but it still cannot locate the element. Attempting to locate it via either @name or @id doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: That element is inside a Select Tag. We handle it in a different manner.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: WebElement month_dropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
Select month=new Select(month_dropdown);
month.selectByValue(“5”); --> we can select the options in a dropdown by using this syntax

Comment: In the hml DOM value is empty, but in the xpath the value is "TX".

Comment: Can you update the Question with your exact manual steps you are trying to automate through script along with the relevant `HTML DOM` for analysis? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but it should work.

```
    //Rather than creating the object of WebElement create object of Select 
    Select stateDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control']"));

    //To select by visible text, pass the text 
    stateDropdown.selectByVisibleText("");

    //Get text of first selected option
    String selectedValue = stateDropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='form-control']/option[text()='TEXAS']")
```